# get the username of the current session in java service

Tags: java, service, windows-7

I am running a java application as a service in windows seven. 
I use a wrapper provided by 'Tanuki software' in order to convert my java application into a windows service and I would like to get the username of the current session for which the service is running.
In my java application, I use the following code: System.getProperty("user.name"). When running as a regular java application, the username is correctly returned but when running as windows service (with the wrapper), the returned username is not the expected one
Which code should I use in my java service in order to get the username of the current session ?
Many thanks
Andre

Answer (score 0):

a service is not run by an user, but the service daemon.

maybe this link will help to run a service as a certain user: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-bamboo-as-a-windows-service-as-the-local-user-416580754.html